# Trying to use .sortBy in a multidimensional array

Tags: node.js, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

I'm trying to sort the "num" of the children in the array which I've first nested:

```
_ = require('underscore');

_.nst = require('underscore.nest');

var data = [
    {'name' : 'name 1', 'num' : 40},
    {'name' : 'name 1', 'num' : 20},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 10},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 50},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 40},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 70},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 30}
];


 //first I nest the data by the "name"
 var newdata = _.nst.nest(data, 'name');

 console.log(newdata);
```

[image: when I log newdata I get:]

But then I try to sort the "num" by highest to lowest within each of the two "name" objects

```
var theSortedChildren0 =  _.sortBy(newdata.children[0].children, 'num');
var theSortedChildren1 =  _.sortBy(newdata.children[1].children, 'num');
```

When I got these the objects are still in their original order (and not sorted by num)

```
    console.log(theSortedChildren0);
    console.log(theSortedChildren1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at this if it solves your problem:

```
var data = [
    {'name' : 'name 1', 'num' : 40},
    {'name' : 'name 1', 'num' : 20},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 10},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 50},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 40},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 70},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 30}
];

var obj = _.chain(data)
           .groupBy('name')
           .map(function ( value) {
              return _.sortBy(value, 'num');
           }).value();

console.log(obj);
```